# Implement jQuery in separated file with html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is from 2 hours that im trying to understand how to use jQuery with a file html, but I can't figure it out!
I want a simple strngh password using jQuery and I found this useful link: http://jsfiddle.net/jquery4u/mmXV5/
My problem now is how allow file html communicate with this script?
my file html is very simple:

```
<form name="register" id="signup" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="register_user.php">
        <div class="header">
            <h3>Registration</h3>
            <p>Complete this form to register.<br/>* required field</p>
        </div>

        <div class="sep"></div>

        <div class="inputs">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" autofocus />*
            <input type="text" placeholder="Surname" name="surname" autofocus />*
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" autofocus />*
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />*

            <div class="sep"></div>
            <div id="messages"></div>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Submit" value="CONFIRM REGISTRATION">                
        </div>
    </form>
```

As you see, javascript file of the link is very consistent so I want to put all codes into another file, but after that I really don't know how to link 2 file and work togheter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.learningjquery.com/)  is a useful link that could help you learn more about jQuery.

You need to add this to your file (in the head or right BEFORE closing the `body` tag).

`<script>src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>`
This allows you to use the jQuery library.
After you include the ajax library from google (this is preferable to be added inside the `<head> *insert here </head>` tags.

Now, if you have an external js file, you just add your jQuery code to it and simply import it in your html file.
`<script src="yourFileWithJquery.js"></script>`. Note that the js file has to be in the same folder with your html file.

Now you are good to go.

Here is a good example on your code:

```
<head>
    <script> src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="myJsFile.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="register" id="signup" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="register_user.php">
                <div class="header">
                    <h3>Registration</h3>
                    <p>Complete this form to register.<br/>* required field</p>
                </div>

                <div class="sep"></div>

                <div class="inputs">
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" autofocus />*
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Surname" name="surname" autofocus />*
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email" autofocus />*
                    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" />*

                    <div class="sep"></div>
                    <div id="messages"></div>
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Submit" value="CONFIRM REGISTRATION">                
                </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Only a minute, im trying :D

Comment: Hi, I tried and "it work"... Result is not the same like in the site!
Im only able to see text with "weak normal or strongh" I didnt see magic bar :D

Comment: What magic bar you want to see? it appears if the password is strong, weak, etc. This was not described in your question.

Comment: If you try to open the link, you will see a bar that change color based on password strength!

Comment: Yes. So? this is not your question, sounds like a good candidate for another question.

Comment: Yeah u are right!
But can you explain why bar is not showed?

Comment: This is too subjective. Depends on your browser, it depends if the methods they use are working or not, on how they display it. Different question, as I said.

If this helped you, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Or simply because you don't have the css file.

Comment: OK thank you guy :D Helpful 100%
PS I dont know how to mark your answer!

Comment: Click the small `tick` under the arrows, and click the ^ arrow